# Can't give access internet to my Android App

Tags: android, manifest, state

I'm working on an app for Android, I need to get a flux from  a website via GET, but I'm stuck on Android Permissions :

I get this message on my Logcat :

```
02-14 21:22:03.607: W/ActivityManager(51): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=***/.*** } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Whereas in my manifest there are those lines before the `<application>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly did you put your permission?
Did you use the Android Manifest xml editor?

try do perform a clean/build

Comment: Already did this, dont work =(.
Those lines are in my Manifst, i tried with the XML editor and without adding manually, same effect. 
Those lines are just before the <application> tag

Comment: Haev you tried putting them AFTER the <application> tag? That's how the Google sample for AdMob does it, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar issue - tried to do something directly from my FreeFoodApp class (extends Application), in the "onCreate()" method, the compiler always returned with "cant start intent ... from a null"
I moved the action to the LAUNCHER activity and it was resolved :)